# Python Classes initialized by equal parameters do not equal

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

Im trying to debug my program, in which two classes, which are initialized by equal (note: `==` comparison not `is`) arguments.
An example code + a snippet of the class + a object comparison is shown below.

Snippet Class Frame

```py
    def __init__(self, frame: PlaywrightFrame, page: Page) -> None:
        super().__init__(frame)
        self._impl_obj = frame._impl_obj
        self._page = page
        self._frame = frame
        self._parent_frame = frame.parent_frame

        self._origin_query_selector = frame.query_selector
        frame.query_selector = self.query_selector
        self._origin_query_selector_all = frame.query_selector_all
        frame.query_selector_all = self.query_selector_all  # type: ignore
        self._origin_wait_for_selector = frame.wait_for_selector
        frame.wait_for_selector = self.wait_for_selector
        self._origin_add_script_tag = frame.add_script_tag
        frame.add_script_tag = self.add_script_tag
        self._origin_add_style_tag = frame.add_style_tag
        frame.add_style_tag = self.add_style_tag
        self._origin_frame_element = frame.frame_element
        frame.frame_element = self.frame_element

        self._origin_evaluate_handle = frame.evaluate_handle
        frame.evaluate_handle = self.evaluate_handle
        self._origin_wait_for_function = frame.wait_for_function
        frame.wait_for_function = self.wait_for_function
        self._origin_frame_locator = frame.frame_locator
        frame.frame_locator = self.frame_locator
        self._origin_locator = frame.locator
        frame.locator = self.locator
```

```py
frame0, page0 = frame._frame, frame._page
frame1, page1 = owner_frame._frame, owner_frame._page
    
print(frame0, frame1, frame0 == frame1)
print(page0, page1, page0 == page1)
    
new_frame0 = Frame(frame0, page0)
new_frame1 = Frame(frame1, page1)
print(new_frame0, new_frame1, new_frame0 == new_frame1)


print(new_frame0.__dict__.items() ^ new_frame1.__dict__.items())
print(DeepDiff(new_frame0, new_frame1))
```

Output

```
<Frame name= url='...'> <Frame name= url='...'> True
<Page url='...'> <Page url='...'> True
<Frame name= url='...'> <Frame name= url='...'> False


{('_origin_wait_for_function', <bound method Frame.wait_for_function of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_locator', <bound method Frame.locator of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_query_selector', <bound method Frame.query_selector of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_wait_for_selector', <bound method Frame.wait_for_selector of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_query_selector_all', <bound method Frame.query_selector_all of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_query_selector_all', <bound method Frame.query_selector_all of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_evaluate_handle', <bound method Frame.evaluate_handle of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_add_script_tag', <bound method Frame.add_script_tag of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_frame_locator', <bound method Frame.frame_locator of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_add_style_tag', <bound method Frame.add_style_tag of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_evaluate_handle', <bound method Frame.evaluate_handle of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_locator', <bound method Frame.locator of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_add_style_tag', <bound method Frame.add_style_tag of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_query_selector', <bound method Frame.query_selector of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_add_script_tag', <bound method Frame.add_script_tag of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_frame_element', <bound method Frame.frame_element of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_frame_locator', <bound method Frame.frame_locator of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_wait_for_function', <bound method Frame.wait_for_function of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_frame_element', <bound method Frame.frame_element of <Frame name= url='...'>>), ('_origin_wait_for_selector', <bound method Frame.wait_for_selector of <Frame name= url='...'>>)}

{'unprocessed': ["root: <Frame name= url='...'> and <Frame name= url='...'>"]}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish with this. Can you clarify the purpose of this class and code in general?

Comment: Im extending the behaviour of Playwright. The Frame class basicly extends the PlaywrightFrame class. But im wondering why my extended class doesnt equal another extended class if the params are equal...

Comment: Why do you want to extend the behavior of Playwright? I don't think it's designed to be subclassed, so there's [probably a better way to achieve whatever underlying goal you have than this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). I have no idea how Frame `__eq__` works or in what case you'd want to use `==`, but when you create separate instances with different URLs, it makes sense to me that they wouldn't be equal. Even if they had the same URL, I don't see that they'd be equal by default, as a quick experiment on the repl shows (see below).

Comment: I know its not meant to be subclassed, thats why i have to be kinda hacky with the _impl_obj. Im extending Playwright for example to make the Typing more fluid.
Note: the urls are the same.

Comment: `class A: def __init__(self, x): self.x = x` then `A(42) == A(42)` gives `False` because the default `__eq__` isn't overridden, so it just uses `is`. I'm not sure that Playwright does the same for its Frame class, but regardless of whether it does or not, the behavior doesn't seem surprising to me, partially since they probably don't expect you to be using `==` on Frames (I doubt a contract is specified in the API docs).

Comment: What do you mean by "make the Typing more fluid" exactly?

Comment: Ok, i just found this weird because Playwrights Frame doesnt use __eq__ , but it still equals. Maybe ill just pass the class as a suboption/under-the-hand option, or create my own __eq__ .

Comment: Does `frame0 is frame1` definitely give False in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend overriding the `__eq__` [method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) of the class, and put in the member variables that you want to compare.

Take the following snippet for example:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self.a = a


obj_1 = SomeClass(1)
obj_2 = SomeClass(1)

print(obj_1 == obj_2)
```

You will see that comparison fails (Output is False) because by default `==` for class objects compares [id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), which will definitely be different.

However, if you override the behaviour to compare the member variables that you want to compare, you can achieve what you desire:

```
from __future__ import annotations


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self.a = a

    def __eq__(self, other: SomeClass):
        if not type(self) == type(other):
            return False

        return self.a == other.a


obj_1 = SomeClass(1)
obj_2 = SomeClass(1)
obj_3 = SomeClass(3)

print(obj_1 == obj_2)
print(obj_1 == obj_3)
```

The output of this is:

```
True
False
```

This is because now it is comparing the two classes as you asked it to compare, and not just the `id`..

Cheers!

Comment: Marking this as valid, figured it out myself but thanks, this is my code now:

    def __eq__(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Frame):
            if (obj._frame == self._frame) and (obj._page == self._page):
                return True
        return False